# unix script error

Tags: unix, scripting

I have the following line in my unix script file:

```
if [[ -f $DIR1/$FILE1 ] -a [ -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ]]; then
```

As clear the line checks for existence of two files in a directory and if both the files are present, some logic will be executed.

However, on running the script I am getting the following error on above line:

```
test_script: line 30: syntax error at line 54: `]' unexpected
```

line 54 is where above line is present.

What does this error mean ? Where am I wrong ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most common shells at least, `[]` are not like parentheses in C where you use then to group subexpressions.

What you need is something like (for `bash`):

```
if [[ -f $DIR1/$FILE1 && -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ]]; then
```

If you want help with a specific (non-`bash`) shell, you should let us know which one you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of [] with -f.

```
if [ -f $DIR1/$FILE1 -a -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ]; then
```

Output:

```
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ touch foo;touch foo2
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ if [ -f "foo"  -a -f "foo2" ]; then echo "Hello"; fi
Hello
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $
```

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that there are multiple answers explaining the subtle differences between [ and [[, but for some reason our culture seems to discourage people from providing the obvious solution.  Stop using '[' entirely.  Instead of '[', use test:

```
if test -f $DIR1/$FILE1 && test -f $DIR1/$FILE2; then
```

Test is cleaner syntax than '[', which requires a final ']' argument and continually confuses people into thinking that the brackets are part of the language.  '[[' is not portable and confuses people who don't realize that many shells provide extra functionality that is non-standard.  There is a case to be made that [[ can be more efficient than [, but if run-time performance is a problem in your shell, you probably shouldn't be solving the problem in sh.

Answer (score 0):

You had extra `[` and `]`

```
if [ -f $DIR1/$FILE1 -a -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ]; then
```

Basically, you were mixing two syntax that aim to do the same thing: namely `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`.  The former is more portable but the latter is more powerful; although the majority of shells you would come across do support `[[ ]]`.

But better still is the following since you are already using the `[[ ]]` construct

```
if [[ -f $DIR1/$FILE1 && -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

As @paxdiablo stated, you can use it this way:

```
if  -f $DIR1/$FILE1 && -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ; then
```

or you can use it this way:

```
if -f $DIR1/$FILE || -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ;
```